# How to append two string array in python

Tags: python

I've two list of string, I'm trying to append both list and would like to add pipe (|) delimiter at the end of string. Please find my code below:

```
firstList = ['Product1,item,,description,price|', 'Product2,item,,description,price|','Product3,item,,description,price|']
secondList = 'Product4,item,,description,price'

result = firstlist + secondList
result.append('|')
print result
```

I want to print my output like below:

```
Product1,item,,description,price|Product2,item,,description,price|Product3,item,,description,price|Product4,item,,description,price|
```

But my code is not appending the pipe delimiter property, its appending as a separate string value in the list. While appending new value in existing list I'm seeing blank space which I don't want.

Can someone please help to resolve this. It would be really helpful if someone can educate what's the efficient way of appending two list in python.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the strings in the first list are already terminated by a pipe? (Note that a final character is a *terminator* not a delimiter.)

Comment: No I don't want to terminate the pipe from both the list.

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment. And it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Do you mean secondList?

Comment: No, I mean the strings in `firstList` already end with pipes. Will this always be the case for every possible input to your program?

Comment: Yes. That's intentional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
firstList = ['Product1,item,,description,price|', 'Product2,item,,description,price|','Product3,item,,description,price|']
secondList = secondList = 'Product4,item,,description,price'
final_list = ''.join(firstList+[secondList[0]+"|"]) if isinstance(secondList, list) else ''.join(firstList+[secondList+"|"])
```

Output:

```
'Product1,item,,description,price|Product2,item,,description,price|Product3,item,,description,price|Product4,item,,description,price|'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is there any option to remove the square bracket and quotes from final output. I've update my output format.

Comment: @learnjquery you cannot remove the quotes as the value itself is a string. However, please see my recent edit to create a stand-alone string.

Comment: its working but after pipe delimiter I'm seeing comma(,) is there any way to remove that too

Comment: This assumes that `secondList` contains exactly one string. A more robust solution will iterate over all the elements of `secondList`.

Comment: Great! Thank you once again

Comment: Actually my secondList is just a string, if i try to append with firstList I'm getting an concatenation error.. Will you code will not work for simple string append to string array? I've update my post

Comment: @learnjquery Please see my recent edit. I made the code more robust so that it will work for when ` secondList ` is either a list or a string.

Answer (score 2):

```
[itm + '|' if not itm.endswith('|') else itm for itm in firstList + secondList]
```

You can use list comprehension to do that with `if-else` condition in it

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to do two different things here. Address each of them separately:

1. Append `'|'` to the end of each string in a list. You can do this with a list comprehension.
2. Concatenate two lists. You can do this with the `+` operator.

I leave the details as an exercise for the reader. Now that you have some terminology, you can google for more information.